# Entity Framework Querying with Navigate Objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

i have entity classes below,i want to a query like sql,how is that posssible with entity framework??

```
select * from SiteUsers su
inner join SiteUserRoles sur on su.Id=sur.SiteUserId
inner join SiteRoleActions sra on sur.SiteRoleId = sra.SiteRoleId
inner join SiteActions sa on sa.Id = sra.SiteActionId
where su.Id=1 and sa.ParentId=189



  public class SiteRole
    {
        public SiteRole()
        {
            this.SiteActions = new HashSet<SiteAction>();
            this.SiteUser = new HashSet<SiteUser>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SiteAction> SiteActions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SiteUser> SiteUser { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class SiteUser
    {
        public SiteUser()
        {
            this.SiteRoles = new HashSet<SiteRole>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string UserPassword { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreated { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SiteRole> SiteRoles { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class SiteAction
    {
        public SiteAction()
        {

            this.Childs = new HashSet<SiteAction>();
            this.SiteRoles = new HashSet<SiteRole>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        public string ControllerName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Type { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<SiteAction> Childs { get; set; }
        public virtual SiteAction Parent { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SiteRole> SiteRoles { get; set; }
    }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SiteUser>().HasMany<SiteRole>(r => r.SiteRoles).WithMany(u => u.SiteUser).Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("SiteUserRoles");
            m.MapLeftKey("SiteUserId");
            m.MapRightKey("SiteRoleId");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<SiteRole>().HasMany<SiteAction>(r => r.SiteActions).WithMany(u => u.SiteRoles).Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("SiteRoleActions");
            m.MapLeftKey("SiteRoleId");
            m.MapRightKey("SiteActionId");
        });



        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have SiteUserRoles and SiteRoleActions as entities but only as join tables (if I read you well), you should use the navigation properties in stead of joining. Something like:

```
conext.SiteUsers.Where(su => su.id == 1
    && su.SiteRoles.SelectMany(sr => sr.SiteActions)
        .Any(sa => sa.ParentId == 189 )
```

(Not syntax checked).

Answer (score 0):

```
  var result=   (from su in SiteUsers
           join sur in SiteUserRoles
           on su.Id=sur.SiteUserId
           join sra in SiteRoleActions
           on sur.SiteRoleId = sra.SiteRoleId
           join sa in SiteActions
           on sra.SiteActionId=sa.Id
           where su.Id=1 and sa.ParentId=189
           select su).ToList();
```

Hope this will help . result will be a list of type SiteUsers.